# semantics of hGet

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a function

```
foo :: Handle -> ByteString
```

which will give me everything that's in the buffer, block if it's empty, and return "" if it's closed.

I've got an app where I'm calling

```
Data.ByteString.Char8.hGet handle 1
```

and everything works adequately, but it's a bit wasteful to call a syscall so many times. Unfortunately if I increase it to even 2, my app gets intermittent hangs, which suggests to me that hGet waits until the buffer is full (or at least bigger than 1).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check either [`hGetNonBlocking`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v%3ahGetNonBlocking) or [`hGetSome`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString.html#v%3ahGetSome). The former never blocks, so it sounds like what you are looking for. The latter blocks until some data is available, but it can returns a shorter ByteString than what was requested.

Comment: hGetSome! That's exactly right, thank you! I think I was misled by looking in Data.ByteString.Char8 - only hGet there.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
hSetBuffering handle NoBuffering
```

**Edit**: actually no, given the fact that you specify the number of bytes you want from `hGet`, it would be surprising if it *didn't* block until *n* bytes are available. Presumably buffering is disabled automatically.